# AppleScript shell script

Tags: applescript, command-line

How can I run a shell script on multiple different computers with the same code? If I have it run from

/users/'my name'/desktop/etc.

then it won't work when I use it on a different computer, because the user name will be different. Is there any way to run it directly without going through the user directory?

Comment: You would use `~/Desktop/blahblahblah`. The `~` is shorthand for "the current user's home directory".

Comment: Further to what @PatrickWynne has stated, if you are referencing these directories from within a shell script, you also have available the shell varialbe `$USER`, which contains the name of the home folder.  So, you would write: `"/Users/$USER/My Folder"`, for example.

Comment: Also not mentioned yet is using `$HOME` in place of `~` as it (`~`) can be problematic, and it's recommended to use `$HOME` over it when using `do shell script` in AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

The AppleScript command I think you're looking for is:

```
(path to Desktop Folder) as text
```

or

```
(path to Desktop Folder)
```

But that would return an HFS path and the code you posted is a POSIX Path so you could change it to:

```
set homePath to POSIX path of (path to Desktop Folder) as text
```

As stated in the comment there is `$USER` for the terminal and per memory you can still call it in AppleScript with something like:

```
do shell script "$USER"
```

If `path to desktop folder` doesn't work you can try just `path to desktop`.

---

### Edit

Addressing the comment. I was taught HFS path and alias path were the same, will make it another question for clarity.

Building the path `as text` is a habit when concat strings or if I was going to take the path and call it later in a `do shell`. For example:

```
(path to desktop folder)
```

in Script Debugger returns an HFS path. When you combine a directory as it was shown in the OP's question a compiling error occurs with:

```
(path to desktop folder & "foobar:")
```

and a

```
(path to desktop folder) & "foobar:"
```

when I've called paths using `path to` I've had to write them as:

```
(path to desktop folder as text) & "foobar:"
```

I was unfamiliar to `short user name of (system info)` and `path to home folder` but that's good to know. One issue with the question is the OP marks it with terminal and AppleScript so the solution is somewhat complicated.

Comment: Some very minor notes: your first code line doesn't return an `alias` path; it returns an HFS path.  Your second code line doesn't require coercing to `text`: `POSIX path` returns a `text` object.  Your third code line is an unnecessary call to a shell script, as the same information can be retrieved via `short user name of (system info)` and also via `system attribute "USER"`.  Likewise, the home folder path can be got with `system attribute "HOME"` (and, of course, the usual `path to home folder` route).

Comment: @CJK edited to answer comment

Comment: @CJK: [asked the question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344344/what-is-the-difference-between-hfs-path-and-alias-path)

Comment: Well done for asking the question to sort through the terminology confusion.  I left a comment against the existing answer to ask if he had any sources to confirm what he's saying, because I haven't yet been able to find any myself.  I'm totally willing to accept that I very well could be wrong here, and I'm certainly far less certain about it now than when I wrote it, so it'd be really good if he can remove the uncertainty for us (by which I mean me).

Comment: Having now read your edit, I still think there's confusion in terminologies here: "`path to desktop folder` in Script debugger returns an HFS path" which isn't correct.  Leaving aside the "HFS path" vs |"alias path" dilemma for now, what we do know is that `path to desktop folder` will always return an `alias`, by which I am referring to both the AppleScript object specifier and the class called "alias". _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ In both uses of the term in AppleScript, it is not a path at all, but an AppleScript object (or its prototype construct) that stores information about a file reference on the OS, which certainly includes the file's path, but other informational properties as well. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ Meanwhile, a path, in my current understanding and in all literature I've read so far (e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)), or [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file)), is a textual string of characters that describes the route through a folder hierarchy that leads to a file.  So `path to desktop folder as text` returns a path, and it happens to be an HFS path.  `POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)` also returns a path, in posix form.  Both are strings. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _..._Cont'd_ This also helps see why you can't concatenate `path to desktop folder` and `":foobar"`, because one returns an object specifier, and the other is a string, so you obviously need to coerce the object to text before joining.  But `POSIX path of...` is a call to retrieve an object's property, and that particular property of an `alias` object is a path, and therefore a string, so won't need a second explicit coercion by way of `...as text`.

Answer (score -1):

This will detect what is the username with which you/script have/has logged in and changes to that directory. you can pre-pend it to your script:

```
     user=`whoami`        
     cd "/Users/$user"
```

Comment: The variable `$USER` already exists in many shells.  Please see my comment against the OP's question.  Also, there would be no need to place `$USER` outside the double quotes.  `cd "/Users/$USER"` is fine.

Comment: Your two line answer could be a one line answer and no need to set a new variable `user` as already mentioned `$USER` should already exist. Not that I would use your answer, but if I did I write it as `cd "/Users/$(whoami)"` instead.