# Strange "Operation not permitted" when automating Keynote via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, permission, keynote

I am on Ventura 13.5. I wrote a little AppleScript to convert directory tree containing Keynote `.key` files into Powerpoint. I am facing strange error:

When I run my script (either from terminal via `osascript` or directly from Script Editor) I get error pop-up from Keynote

> "File1" can’t be opened right now.
> Operation not permitted

I go to Finder, double-click the File**1** and it opens nicely in Keynote. I close the Keynote and re-run the script, now I get error for File**2**. I again manually open File**2**, re-run and get error on File**3**, etc.

So basically I am getting error on every file, but when I open it manually from Finder it's OK and after that it's OK even for the script.

There must be some limit to it though. When I tried to open first 10 files, they all worked then. But when I tried more, the File**1** became the issue again.

I think that at some point I have seen the issue even in Finder - error first time, then file opened fine. But I don't see that any more.

Simplest code to reproduce is this:

```
on run argv
    set fileToOpen to (item 1 of argv)
    
    tell application "Keynote"
        activate
        open fileToOpen
    end tell
end run
```

which then could be run from terminal as (use just any Keynote file)

```
osascript openkeynote.applescript ~/Downloads/Sample.key
```

Produces the error. When I open it from finder and try script again it works. When I then `cp Sample.key Sample2.key` the `Sample2.key` has the problem again.

I would be glad for advice on how to troubleshoot and fix this.

So far I have tried to remove the `com.apple.quarantine` xattr from the files, but that did not help. I did not try to disable System Integrity Protection (which is recommended in some places), as that feels like not right solution.

**Update 1**: Reproduction snippet added. My Keynote is version 12.2.1 (7035.0.161).

Comment: You are likely to get better help if you share your AppleScript code.

Comment: @Alper thanks for suggestion, the reproduction snippet added.

Comment: Is it possible that it was failing because *fileToOpen* as just a string? i.e. unlike in your solution, it doesn't have a `posix file` in front of it here.

Comment: @Mockman You are right. String is the problem, posix file or alias work fine (I would presume file too). I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that open does not work well with string paths. Those only work of the file is in the recent. However, the `POSIX file` or `alias` work fine. (for more details on  those see Apple Automation Scripting Guide's [Reference on Files and Folders](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html) or the other [Ask Diferent Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344344/what-is-the-difference-between-hfs-path-and-alias-path)).

Working script:

```
on run argv
    set fileToOpenAsString to (item 1 of argv)
    set fileToOpenAsPosixFile to POSIX file fileToOpenAsString
    set fileToOpenAsAlias to fileToOpenAsPosixFile as alias
    
    tell application "Keynote"
        activate
        
        (* This only works when the file is in File -> Open Recent menu *)
        open fileToOpenAsString
        
        (* This always works *)
        open fileToOpenAsPosixFile
        
        (* This always works *)
        open fileToOpenAsAlias
    end tell
end run
```